# Webgl full screen blending slowdown

Tags: webgl, gpu

I've tried to make an "overlay" effect in a 3d scene. After drawing stuff to the buffer, i tried to draw a full screen quad with blending enabled and the depth test disabled. On some android devices this seems to have caused a slow down.

I found this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25929/ios-opengl-transparency-performance-issue):

> The particularly slow point is the point where the drawing of a pixel needs to check what the color behind it was.

So instead of drawing a single full screen quad, i divided it up in tiles, and rendered with multiple draw calls, which seems to have caused some gain.

What may be happening here and how can this be profiled with webgl i.e. how does one come to the conclusion from the quote above?

Comment: Many first and 2nd generation android devices can not draw more than about 1.5 screens worth of pixel before slowing down. This is really bad for WebGL because WebGL requires compositing. So if you have a fullscreen WebGL page on a browser first your render an image to the canvas (that's 1 full screen of drawing). Then the canvas gets rendered to composite it with the page. That's another full screen have drawing. Adding in your post process pass is yet another full screen of drawing. Even my 2015 MBP can only draw about 10 full screens of pixels before hitting the 60fps limit.

Comment: This is even when those 10 full screens of pixels are nothing but a constant color?

Comment: Yes, constant color but with blending enabled.

Comment: What type of reading can I do in order to understand why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that to profile it, you simply have to test with several blending function, with or without blending enabled, etc...

Blending is not a trivial operation, and indeed we can assume that blending function which need to read pixel on buffer could induce performance lose, like all "reading" operation in OpenGL, because this can block the pipeline. I guess most of modern desktop GPU have some specific design to optimize this, but on mobile phones, this is maybe more problematic.

Anyway, if you are about to draw a full screen quad, why don't you render your quad directly using two source texture, which you blend directly in the fragment shader using a custom equation ? this way, you don't need to use blending and you avoid any back buffer reading problem.

Comment: Well, the one thing for sure i would be forfeiting is the antialiasing correct? I also actually wanted to ask if what is happening might be similar to what would happen if i tried to read an entire texture. Rendering in tiles seems to have done something.

Comment: If you are limited to WebGL 1.0, this is true, you will lose MSAA if you work only with textures. I think reading an entire texture is not a problem because this is intented to work this way: `read texture => fragment shader => write buffer`, so no blocking in pipeline. I guess problem occurs because blending need to read the back buffer: `fragment shader => read buffer => blending => write buffer`. why the problem is reduced using tiles ? Probably because all this is related to memory bandwidth and access...

Comment: My theory is : when a memory block must be read, all the writing process must be stopped until read operation finished. If you divide in tiles, the writing operation is blocking only on one "tile", but others can continue. In GPU, all is parallelized, this is both the strength and the weakness of the concept.